# Number $f(x)$ whose representation in base 3 is the binary representation of $x$: when does $x$ divide $f(x)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

For any natural number $x$, let $f(x)$ be the natural number whose representation in base 3 is the same as the binary representation of $x$ (for instance, $f(5)=10$ because $5=101_2$ and $101_3=10$). Are there infinitely many $x$ such that $f(x)$ is a multiple of $x$? What about the odd ones among them? Besides the numbers 1 and 49091, are there other natural numbers $x$ of the considered kind such that $f(x)$ is odd (i.e. such that the binary representation of $x$ contains an odd number of 1's)?

An additional question (concerning a possible upper bound for the considered numbers): are there natural numbers $x$ greater than $2^{36}$ such that $f(x)$ is a multiple of $x$? (An $x$ between $2^{35}$ and $2^{36}$ with the considered property is indicated in my comment of August 9, 2019; if the comment is not displayed correctly please look at https://store.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/fmi/logic/skordev/Aug-comments.pdf).

**Some answers.**

1. An answer to the above additional question can be found in my third comment of November 25, 2019 (if the comment in question is not displayed correctly please look at the second of my later comments). A number greater than $2^{41}$ and having the property in question is indicated there.
2. Among the nine numbers $x$ with $x\!\mid\!f(x)$ which have been added by Giovanni Resta in December 2019, there are two with odd values of $f(x)$, namely the numbers 7603017182731 and 35401601113345.

Comment: The first 35 of these numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A062845

Comment: A computer search fails to find any other instances with $x\le 2^{32}$.

Comment: To @TonyK: I suppose your search yields all natural numbers  _x_ in the range in question such that f(_x_) is a multiple of _x_. If so, could you please indicate which is the largest odd one among them.

Comment: $49091$ is the largest $x\le 2^{32}$ such that $f(x)$ is odd. Sorry, I thought I had made that clear. (My program only outputs the odd ones.)

Comment: My question was about the largest odd _x_ in that range such that f(_x_) is a multiply of _x_, no matter whether f(_x_) is odd or even. Maybe the misunderstanding is due to my poor English.

Comment: You said "such that $f(x)$ is odd", which seemed clear to me.

Comment: In the question to you added on July 1, I meant the largest one among the odd _x_ in the range examined by you such that f(_x_) is a multiply of _x_ (without the requirement f(_x_) to be odd too). There are such _x_, for instance the number 16596055, but I do not know which is the largest one among them.

Comment: In the second sentence of the above comment, I mean "In the range in question, there are odd _x_ greater than 49091 such that f(_x_) is a multiply of _x_".

Comment: The odd natural numbers _x_ known to me such that f(_x_) is a multiple of _x_ are the following ones: 1, 5, 215, 27125, 49091, 16596055, 95756071. The corresponding quotients f(_x_) / _x_ are 1, 2, 14, 242, 341, 8500, 30628.

Comment: The number 10819605888 is the largest among the natural numbers _x_ known to me such that f(_x_) is a multiple of _x_ (the corresponding quotient f(_x_) / _x_ equals 571131).

Comment: I found two larger natural numbers _x_ with the property that f(_x_) is a multiple of _x_, namely the number 12062781906 and its double 24125563812. The corresponding quotients f(_x_) / _x_ are 530042 and 795063.

Comment: Basically, you are asking whether there are infinitely many $(k+1)$-tuples $(c_0,c_1,\dotsc,c_k)\in\{0,1\}^{k+1}$ such that $c_k2^k+\dotsb+2c_1+c_0$ is a divisor of $c_k3^k+\dotsb+3c_1+c_0$, correct?

Comment: Of course the problem whether there are infinitely many natural numbers _x_ such that f(_x_) is a multiple of _x_ can be formulated as in the above comment.

Comment: To be precise, I ought to add to my previous comment the statement that $c_k=1$ should be taken for granted in Seva's one.

Comment: I found a natural number $x$ greater than $2^{35}$ such that $f(x)$ is a multiple of $x$. This $x$ is 63872958240, and the corresponding quotient $f(x)/x$ equals 1144859. I replace now $2^{35}$ with $2^{36}$ in my question.

Comment: If $n>0$ is an integer, and the integers $i,x,k,u,l,v\ge 0$ are determined from $n=2^ix$, $x\ \textrm{mod}\ 2\ne 0$, $x=3^ku$, $u\ \textrm{mod}\ 3\ne 0$, $f(x)=2^lv$, $v\ \textrm{mod}\ 2\ne 0$, then $f(n)$ is divisible by $n$ iff $v$ is divisible by $u$ and $k\le i\le l$. To look for integers $n>0$ with $f(n)$ divisible by $n$, we may look for odd integers $x>0$ s.t. $v$ is divisible by $u$ and $k\le l$ for the integers $k,u,l,v\ge 0$ determined by $x=3^ku$, $u\ \textrm{mod}\ 3\ne 0$, $f(x)=2^lv$, $v\ \textrm{mod}\ 2\ne 0$. To any such $x$, the numbers $n=2^ix$, $i=k,\ldots,l$, correspond.

Comment: Here is a proof for the first statement in my previous comment. Under the assumptions of this statement, the equalities $f(n)=3^if(x)=3^i2^lv$, $n=2^i3^ku$ hold, and the number $u$ is odd. In addition, $f(x)\ \textrm{mod}\ 3\ne 0$ due to the oddity of $x$, hence $v\ \textrm{mod}\ 3\ne 0$. If $f(n)$ is divisible by $n$ then $3^i2^lv$ is divisible by $u$, by $2^i$ and by $3^k$, therefore $v$ is divisible by $u$ and $k\le i\le l$. Conversely, if $v$ is divisible by $u$ and $k\le i\le l$ then obviously $f(n)$ is divisible by $n$.

Comment: Here is an example of applying the method indicated in my comment before the previous one. For $x=24617224107$, we have $x=3^7u$, $u\ \textrm{mod}\ 3=2$, $f(x)=19248170744129152=2^7v$, $v\ \textrm{mod}\ 2=1$ and $v$ is divisible by $u$ with
$u=11256161$, $v=150376333938509$, therefore $f(n)$ is divisible by $n$ for $n=2^7x=3151004685696$ (note that $n>2^{41}$).

Comment: Perhaps someone would like to update the OEIS page referenced in the 1st comment?

Comment: Several days ago, 75 further terms of the sequence A062845 have been added.

Comment: My comments of November 25 use LaTeX for the mathematical expressions, but there is a problem with these expressions now, namely Firefox skips them or replaces them with sequences of dots (at least on my computer). A PDF file with these comments can be found at https://store.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/fmi/logic/skordev/25Nov-comments.pdf.

Comment: The dots mentioned in my previous comment turned out to be commas.

Comment: Giovanni Resta added 9 more terms of the sequence. The third of them is the number *n* mentioned in my third message of November 25. The previous two of the 9 terms in question can be obtained in the same way by using the number 39035442699 as *x*. Unfortunately obtaining these three terms in such a way does not show that they are the first three terms of the sequence after the last one of the previously added 75 terms.

Comment: At the present moment, the 15-digits number 482017075506000 is the largest natural number *x* known to me such that f(*x*) is a multiple of *x*. This number is the double of the term before the last one among the nine terms added by Giovanni Resta.

Comment: A considerably larger number with the property in question is already known, namely the 16-digits number 6961876166204120. In addition, one eighth of it is the largest presently known odd number with this property.

Comment: Meanwhile, two still larger numbers with the considered property have been observed, namely 8378872210440822 and twice this number.

Comment: A larger odd number with the considered property has been observed, namely 4715881247031413.